# Perform Background task in java

Tags: java, multithreading, background-process

Just like we have AsyncTask in android , what options do we have in Java to perform task running in background(different Thread) and as well communicate with the main Thread easily .

I have found things like

1.Worker Threads and

2.swing workers

please let me know if these are the correct classes to do such work , as well what else i can use to do above mention work

Comment: Swingworkers are good only for desktop apps using swing.

Comment: Are you talking about Java in general, or related to any particular UI toolkit like AWT, Swing, SWT, JFace, ...?

Comment: No i'm talking about java in general , for performing background talk what class should one be using??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multi-threading/tasking in general, Java has terrific concurrency support. Check out java.util.concurrent. And to communicate with the main thread perhaps java.util.obsever and java.util.observable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want parallel tasks in general (not related to any UI toolkit), and you don't alrady use a framework that offers some high-level concurrency mechanisms (like the eclipse Job API), you should have a look at the `java.util.concurrent` package - especially `Executor` and `ExecutorService`.

Example:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);

// somewhere else:
executor.execute(myRunnableTask); // myRunnableTask is a Runnable

// or, if you want to have more control
Future<Double> futureResult = executor.submit(myCallableCalculation);
// ...
Double result = futureResult.get(); // waits until calculation completes
```

See also:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Answer (score 0):

For multi-threading/tasking in general, Java has terrific concurrency support.  Check out java.util.concurrent. And to communicate with the main thread perhaps java.util.obsever and java.util.observable.